# Jython exceeding recursion limit with Gson

Tags: java, python, recursion, gson, jython

I'm using Jython to make a Gson call to the method toJson(). I used a GsonBuilder to create the Gson object. The problem is that when calling the method, I get a 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.' This is coming from the getAdapter() method inside the toJson call, both methods being a part of the Gson class of course.

Basically, the toJson method calls other toJson methods in the class with different signatures based on the inputs.Of course Gson comes as a jar so there's no changing it and I'm not seeing where the recursion lies in the getAdapter method. Has anyone done anything like this before and know a workaround/hack and I can use? Quick and dirty is fine, I just need this for a proof of concept. The relevant code is as follows.

```
builder = GsonBuilder()
builder.registerTypeAdapter(tpj.Semicircles(0).class, app.SemicirclesTypeAdapter())
gson = builder.setPrettyPrinting().create()
payload = tp.RequestPayload()
payload.setFMI(sr)
json = gson.toJson(payload)
System.out.println(json)
```

tpj is a python module and app is the Java class I'm trying to emulate with the Jython. Emulating the Gson stuff would be too complicated which is why I'm using Jython.

Comment: can you give a stacktrace? or specific error that it is giving you?

Comment: I bet payload spans an object graph with cycles.